# Second frame window linked to 1st frame is not showing the content-java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm using eclipse for my assignment and the 2nd frame content is not showing anything only the window is opening meaning window 1 closes and window 2 opens but the content and design I created is not showing

this is the first window code

```
package GUI;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class LaunchGUI extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    LaunchGUI frame = new LaunchGUI();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public LaunchGUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 722, 470);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        
        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Sign In");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                LoginGUI1 login = new LoginGUI1();
                login.setVisible(true);
                LaunchGUI.this.dispose();
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(35, 211, 97, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
        
        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Sign Out");
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(543, 211, 97, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton_1);
        
        JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Start Game");
        btnNewButton_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                MainGameGUI start = new MainGameGUI();
                start.setVisible(true);
                LaunchGUI.this.dispose();
            }
        });
        btnNewButton_2.setBounds(292, 211, 97, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton_2);
        
        JButton btnNewButton_3 = new JButton("View Score");
        btnNewButton_3.setBounds(494, 339, 97, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton_3);
        
        JButton btnRegister = new JButton("Register");
        btnRegister.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                
            }
        });
        btnRegister.setBounds(61, 339, 97, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnRegister);
    }

}
```

This is the second window code

```
package GUI;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class LoginGUI1 extends JFrame{

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JPasswordField passwordField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    LoginGUI1 window = new LoginGUI1();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public LoginGUI1() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 721, 526);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(258, 236, 116, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
        btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
        btnLogin.setBounds(258, 386, 97, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnLogin);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Username");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(157, 239, 68, 16);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Password");
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(163, 301, 56, 16);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1);

        passwordField = new JPasswordField();
        passwordField.setBounds(258, 298, 116, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(passwordField);
    }
}
```

I can't seem to understand the mistake I have made please help!!!!

Comment: Your code extends JFrame and then in the constructor you create another JFrame, so you have two instances of a frame. The one that you make visible has no components.  Don't extend JFrame. Just make the "frame" visible in the constructor after you add all the components to the frame.

Answer (score 1):

You do ...

```
public class LoginGUI1 extends JFrame {
```

Then you do ...

```
private JFrame frame;
//...
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
```

So, the question is, which frame is which?

So, when you do...

```
LoginGUI1 login = new LoginGUI1();
login.setVisible(true);
LaunchGUI.this.dispose();
```

You making the "class" frame visible, not the `frame` property of `LoginGUI1` visible.

This is a really good example of why you should avoid extending directly from `JFrame`.  Start by extending from `JPanel` instead

```
public class LoginGUI1 extends JPanel {

    private JTextField textField;
    private JPasswordField passwordField;

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public LoginGUI1() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        // This is a bad idea
        setLayout(null);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(258, 236, 116, 22);
        add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
        btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
        btnLogin.setBounds(258, 386, 97, 25);
        add(btnLogin);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Username");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(157, 239, 68, 16);
        add(lblNewLabel);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Password");
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(163, 301, 56, 16);
        add(lblNewLabel_1);

        passwordField = new JPasswordField();
        passwordField.setBounds(258, 298, 116, 22);
        add(passwordField);
    }
}
```

Now, when you want to display it, you either add it to what ever container you want or create a new window for it

```
LoginGUI1 login = new LoginGUI1();
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setBounds(100, 100, 721, 526);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.add(login);
```

## Feedback

`null` layouts are going to come back and byte you.  Instead of wasting a lot of time, you should take the time to learn how to make use of the various layout managers that are available to you.  See [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more details.

In fact, instead of trying to create multiple windows, you should consider making use of [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)